# Rails 5 Resource Routing Error Only In Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, phusion, pony

I have a perfectly normal resource defined by `resources :products`.

Update works fine in development, on my laptop on pony. Production is on a server I don't have a lot of control of, using phusion. Whenever I try to update it redirects mysteriously, giving me a 404. This is what is in the log:

```
64d8] Completed 200 OK in 57ms (Views: 9.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
I, [2018-08-03T13:42:22.444552 #2652091]  INFO -- : [dde252e5-5750-4f63-9fd2-b02a882c864c] Started PATCH "/products/578" for > 154.20.31.78 at 2018-08-03 13:42:22 -0700
F, [2018-08-03T13:42:22.445282 #2652091] FATAL -- : [dde252e5-5750-4f63-9fd2-b02a882c864c]
F, [2018-08-03T13:42:22.445332 #2652091] FATAL -- : [dde252e5-5750-4f63-9fd2-b02a882c864c] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/578"):
```

As you can see, it seems to be changing the route somewhere I have no access to.

EDIT: The form starts:

```rb
<%= form_with model: product, local: true do |form| %>
```

And populates correctly for /products/id/edit. This produces the html:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/products/578" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="g+oaySVsX4QLZSvII9xbEZo3j0lGChrXSHhMUdUyJ+3eZEUK6iC6QK4sa1SkdBX6f2vvH2HXlN+rR5lzQOmDWA==" />
```

This is the relevant method in the controller, which, judging from logging experiments, never seems to be touched. Curiously enough, the forms which trigger `format.js` work perfectly well.

```rb
def update
  verify_admin
  respond_to do |format|
    @product.update(product_params)
    if @product.save
      save_picture if params[:product][:picture_file]
      if params[:commit] == 'Add/Edit'
        format.html { redirect_to products_url(@product) }
      else
        format.js { render inline: 'location.reload()' }
      end
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller that is doing this?

Comment: I have carefully verified that the program never touches the update method in the controller.

Comment: Then can you post the snippet of the view that renders the link for the PATCH operation?

Comment: Okay, I edited into the post.

Comment: I added that controller snippet, and added some extra info. Just ate and I'm thinking a little more clearly.

Comment: Where are you generating this link `/578` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It should be /products/578. That's what the url says when it gives me the 404. [GET] /products/578 works fine. [POST] /products/578 works on a smaller form

Comment: Can you do a rake routes in production and see if patch redirects to /update?

Comment: can you reproduce this on localhost `rails s -e production` ?

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: No, all I could figure out was that it was uploading the picture that triggered the bug. Otherwise update works fine. Using the same way of uploading a picture with create is no problem.